# Search a XMLNODE

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am very new to XML handling in ASP .NET.

I am consuming data of a sharepoint list in asp .net site through web service reference.

following is my code for consuming data.

```
TestSharePointSite.Lists lists = new global::Test.TestSharePointSite.Lists();

lists.Url = "http://intranetsharepoint/global/test/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
lists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

XmlNode n = lists.GetListItems("TestList", null, null, null, null, null, null);

for (int i = 0; i < n.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes.Count; i++)
{
    if (n.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[i].Attributes != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlAttribute a in n.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[i].Attributes)
        {
            Response.Write("<br> .. " + a.Name + " .. " + a.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

And following is my output from the above code

```
.. ows_Content_x0020_Description .. string;#Fast Track
.. ows_Dev_x002e__x0020_Location .. 32;#Numatics Actuator Tennessee
.. ows_Strategic_x0020_Bucket0 .. 4;#Minor Revision
--------------------- Other Attributes ----------------
.. ows_Engineer .. 584;#Tilmos, Wayne [INDAUTO/ASCONUM/NOVI]
.. ows__ModerationStatus .. 0
```

now i want to search a particular XML element\XML node. I want a node  in which content description ( here it comes with name `ows_Content_x0020_Description`) contains `Fast Track`.

I have gone through following questions on SO but not able to implement the solution in my code. i have tried to search on google too but not able to do it.  thx in advance.

[Select XML node by attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963190/select-xml-node-by-attribute-value)

[Find XmlNode where attribute value is contained in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263523/find-xmlnode-where-attribute-value-is-contained-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   XmlDocument dddd = new XmlDocument();
            dddd.Load(@"D:\Development\xxxx\xxxxx.xml");
            XmlNode xnode = dddd.DocumentElement;
            for (int i = 0; i < xnode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            { 
               if(xnode.ChildNodes[i].Attributes !=null)
                   foreach (XmlAttribute a in xnode.ChildNodes[i].Attributes)
                   {
                       if (a.Name == "ows_Content_x0020_Description")
                       {
                           string nameddd = a.InnerText;
                       }
                   }

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use XPath expression to test. I'm assuming variable list is an XmlDocument.

```
XmlNode node = 
  list.SelectSingleNode("//root/ows_Content_x0020_Description[contains(.,'Fast Track')]");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode.aspx

Edit: Test you XPath expression using [XPathTester](http://www.xpathtester.com/)

Comment: it is giving me following error '//root/ows_Content_x0020_Description/Fast Track' has an invalid token. please note that the value of "ows_Content_x0020_Description" is "string;#Fast Track" not "Fast Track"

Comment: I just made a guess at the path name. You would need to adapt it. Just wanted to showcase how easy it is to use XPath compared to having to write foreach loops.

Comment: ok i got your point .. but the thing is i will not be able going to search on exact value but i need to select node which will contain given value .. some kind of wild card search (something like '%Fast 
Track%')

Comment: i think this is the best way to do this thx but i would accept suraj's answer because there are some issues at service level